# How can I find out which provinces are owned by another (enemy) country?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

Is there an in-game way to find out which provinces are owned by another (enemy) country? (I don't want to resort to the console.)

As background, I'm playing as the Ottomans. Byzantium has re-emerged in Cyprus. Cyprus is their capital, and I thought Cyprus was their only province. I now occupy Cyprus, but cannot fully annex Byzantium. I presume they control another province, but I don't know which one. I want to find out so that I can send my army there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well a few days back when I was trying to find out why it was so hard for me to annex an enemy.

As usual, the **ledger** holds the answers.

First off, you can easily check if your opponent really has more provinces than you thought in the ***Number of Provinces*** page in the ledger. Just deselect everything and select only the target country:

[image]

Unfortunately, this wont show you where those provinces are located.

After some searching I noticed that this info can be found in the ***Goods Locations*** page in the ledger, which has the main purpose of showing you where to find certain trade goods:

[image]

By clicking on the *Country* header you can sort by country alphabetical. From there it should be easy for you to scroll to the country you search for.

However, if a province is within *Terra Incognita* (you haven't discovered it yet), it will only show as *???* and you will not be able to conquer it until discovery.

Comment: Nifty idea, although it's still a bit of a pain. In For the Glory, I finally got fed up and added a tooltip to the warscore percentage if the enemy controls three or fewer provinces.

Comment: Thank you very much!  The game got very evil with colors on me--the offending province that I couldn't find is almost exactly the same color as the nation it's embedded in.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easiest just to go into the diplomatic mapmode, click on a country, and then every province owned by the nation will appear in bright green, all you have to do is look around for it.

Answer (score -1):

An alternate solution, if you can use the console in your game:
what you can do is save, then open up the console, type in "tag [Country tag]" and then you will be playing as that country. Then, what you can do is type in "cash" for 5000 ducats, and then build on all the provinces you know about.

After that, you can hover over the icon showing you which provinces are possible to build in, and it will name the provinces (if there are less than 2), or you can try finding it otherwise.

I had this problem and was going to solve it by vassalizing and annexing the country (Aragon).
[I was looking to find out how to raise my diplomatic power in console to do it faster, and couldn't figure out how to add idea groups, and stumbled upon this solution]
For me, the problematic province was Malta. Stupid tiny islands! (: